# Alterar valores de uma array bidimensional - PHP

Tags: php, array, array-multidimensional

Olá.

Preciso montar um `foreach` para atualizar os valores do array abaixo:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
        [id] => 1
        [profissao] => Ajudante de cozinha
        [interesse] => 
       )

   [1] => Array
       (
        [id] => 2
        [profissao] => Manobrista
        [interesse] => 
       )

   [2] => Array
       (
        [id] => 3
        [profissao] => Porteiro
        [interesse] => 
       )

   [3] => Array
       (
        [id] => 4
        [profissao] => Vigia
        [interesse] => 
       )

   [4] => Array
       (
        [id] => 5
        [profissao] => Zelador
        [interesse] => 
       )

   [5] => Array
       (
        [id] => 6
        [profissao] => Arrumadeira
        [interesse] => 
       )

   [6] => Array
       (
        [id] => 7
        [profissao] => BabÃ¡
        [interesse] => 
       )

   [7] => Array
       (
        [id] => 8
        [profissao] => BabÃ¡ folgista
        [interesse] => 
       )

   [8] => Array
       (
        [id] => 9
        [profissao] => Caseiro
        [interesse] => 
       )

   [9] => Array
       (
        [id] => 10
        [profissao] => Copeira(o)
        [interesse] => 
       )
)
```

Comment: Como você quer que a array fique no final?

Comment: Só preciso atualizar os valores do interesse, ([interesse] => 1), percorrer o vetor e atualizar os valores @bfavaretto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode percorre-la assim:

```
foreach($myArray as $key => $subarray) {
      $myArray[$key]['interesse'] = '1';
      // ...
}
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://ideone.com/gjrXzd)</kbd>